# Attaching database on SQL Server, PowerShell cursor comes to next line

Tags: database, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that iterates over multiple database files and should attach all of them one by one. However after attaching first database file, the script just stops and comes to next line as if looking for some user input.

Script

```
ForEach ($_ in $File)
{
    if(true)
        {
            & sqlcmd -S $DBSERVERNAME -q $attachDB   
            Write-host "Attached First"
        } 

    if(true)
        {
            & sqlcmd -S $DBSERVERNAME -q $attachDB
            Write-host "Attached Second"
        }
}
```

Output

Attached First

1>

If I press enter next it goes to next line

2>

How do I make my script continue to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused as Sqlcmd [switches are case sensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15), a quite uncommon case for Windows applications.

> -q "cmdline query"
>
> -Q "cmdline query" (and exit)

As for fix, use capital Q to run the query and exit Sqlcmd.